# jQuery background submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this is yet another form submit question. Sorry for that - but I can't find the mistake/error. The script doesn't work as expected. :(

EDIT (sorry): It should load the "test" into the div from the PHP and should post the serialized data from the form.

In the PHP-File is only a echo"test"; line.

Here is my JS:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#rate_").submit(function() {
            var dataString = $("#rate").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "rateit.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#ratesucess").html("working");  
                    console.log('working: '+msg);
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    $("#ratesucess").html("not working ");  
                    console.log('not working '+msg);
                }
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

Here the HTML-Code:

```
<div id="ratesucess"></div>
    <div id="vote">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="rate_">
            <h3>Einrichtungen</h3>      
            <label for="star_10">Shop</label>

            <input name="star_10" type="radio" class="star" value="1" />        
            <input name="star_10" type="radio" class="star" value="2" />        
            <input name="star_10" type="radio" class="star" value="3" />        
            <input name="star_10" type="radio" class="star" value="4" />        
            <input name="star_10" type="radio" class="star" value="5" /><br />
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: What is the problem? The error?

Comment: *'The script doesn't work as expected'* - What *is* expected?

Comment: So is it rate or rate_

Comment: The id=rate_ with "_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not cancel the form submission

```
$("#rate_").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

and you are missing an underscore on an id

```
var dataString = $("#rate_").serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your error is that:

```
var dataString = $("#rate").serialize();
```

And your form id is :

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="rate_">
```

So fix id="**rate_**" to id="**rate**"

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix the problem.